# Could not resolve dependencies: org.springframework.transaction

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I am not super confident in my understanding of Maven so bear with me:

My POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Build:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:org.springframework.transaction:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.427 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-02T15:22:42-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project PROJECT: Could not resolve dependencies for project PROJECT:jar:1.0: Failure to find org.springframework:org.springframework.transaction:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven2 has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Looking in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 this makes sense. `org.springframework.transaction` is indeed not present in the repository. So I went to [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org.springframework.transaction/3.2.4.RELEASE) and noticed that it says the artifact lives in the following repository:

https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/

This time, looking through the repository I did find `org.springframework.transaction` at the directory matching the groupId and artifactId specified in my POM.

https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/springframework/org.springframework.transaction/

However there is clearly no `3.2.4.RELEASE` here. My co-worker's are able to build the project (though it has been some time since they checked it out fresh) and they remember running into a similar issue. I am a little confused as to why this feels like a repository issue though when we are all running the same POM.

As an aside, there are multiple other `org.springframework` dependencies that are resolving appropriately and I can see them in my `~/.m2`, just not this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being an issue to having `spring-context` dependency in my pom. Apparently that does stuff for you? Getting rid of both `spring-tx` and `org.springframework.transaction` actually allowed them to be downloaded and accessed properly.

Answer (score 1):

The org.springframework.transaction has the spring-tx artifact id.

I use this snippet in my pom and works seamlessly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RElEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have seen the `spring-tx` artifact but the project will not build with it. My coworker's `.m2`s all have the `org.springframework.transaction` artifactId. It definitely exists as evidenced by the link in my question

Comment: actually, this appears to have fixed most of my issues, but it is complaining about cannot find `spring-dao` despite the imports from dao that I am using being present in the `spring-tx` jar

Comment: my build complains about `package org.springframework.dao does not exist` but when I inspect the `spring-tx-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar` in my `.m2` I can see that it does

Comment: The spring-tx itself does not depends on spring-dao. I think you have some other package depending on spring-dao. I you should choose the proper version  from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-dao) and include the snippet to your pom.

Answer (score 0):

Your .m2 does not have it and Maven tries to get it from defined repositories. You do not have them or you do not have a connection from Maven. (it is more likely from what error says as I remember). are you behind the proxy?

You need to define additional repositories. either in ~/.m2/settings.xml or inside POM on project level.

Something like that:

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
                <id>fuse-public-repository</id>
                <name>FuseSource Community Release Repository</name>                            
                 <url>https://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
 <repositories>
```

in settings.xml usually in one of the active profile element.
 In POM just inside project.

PS. be sure you have connection to the repository URL. If you are behind proxy you need to define it as well in settings.xml

Comment: I'm not sure what is alfresco repository, there are bunch of repositories with Spring artifacts, but whatever... :)

Comment: I updated answer. It must be about connection from Maven as I remember when such "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository" error appears

Answer (score 0):

As @Vadim just answered, you just need to add your custom repo to your pom.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>alfresco</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
         <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/releas‌​e</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And then you can get your dependency by using:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

You can view the repository contents by using this link https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/#nexus-search;quick~transaction

Also be carefull not to run maven with -o flag( or in offline mode ) for the first time in order to let maven to download the dependency.

Comment: thats not the version my project uses though? This is what I need, but cannot find: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/org.springframework.transaction/3.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: It seems that this version is the latest available of your dependency on this repository.

Comment: I understand that.. hence the question.

Comment: Your dependency is available in the springsource release bundle. Please try the following and let me know if it works.`<repositories><repository>
      <id>my-repo1</id>
      <name>your custom repo</name>
      <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>`

Comment: nope. switching to `spring-tx` appears to have fixed most of the problems, however now I am not able to find `org.springframework.dao` despite it being inside the `spring-tx` jar